# Export ubuntu/linux from virtual machine to install it on physical machine

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

Is it possible to

1. configure a linux system on a virtual machine (install software, configure settings, ...)
2. then export this system including preserving its current state (installed software, configured settings, ...)
3. and then installing the system with its current state on a physical machine?

EDIT: This would be a comfortable way to test out certain configurations and software on an OS before actually installing it on a physical machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I used qemu to accomplish this task for me.

Run `sudo apt install qemu-utils to install` qemu and include the source and target directory.

For example: `sudo qemu-img convert -p -O raw '/media/D2/Virtualbox VMs/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 Old Desktops/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 Old Desktops.vhd' /dev/sde.`